# Bind browser storage to the view in Angular2

Tags: angular, web-sql

I use webSql database to store data and I want to bind the stored data to the view in Angular2 i.e. if the stored data change, the changes should automatically reflect in the view. 
Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Please check out the documentation on [angular.io](https://angular.io). There are many examples of how to bind properties to the template. As far as using web-sql, simply work with it as you always have in either the component, or better: abstract it into a service.

Comment: look at [angular-localforage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage).  There is the ability to bind directly to an object or directive

Comment: #SnareChops I checked the Angular2 documentation but couldn't find anything related to web storage binding , could you please send me the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind a property directly to a webSQL database. Instead you need to wrap the implementation in a service, and then use the service in your component.

```
@Injectable()
export class WebSQLService{
    read(){ ... }
    create(){ ... }
    update(){ ... }
    delete(){ ... }
}

@Component({
    template: `<input [ngModel]="myProp" (ngModelChange)="myProp = $value"/>`
})
export class MyComponent{
    // Private property to hold the current value
    private _myProp;
    // Setter to propagate changes to the database automatically
    set myProp(value){
        this.updateSql(value);
        this._myProp = value;
    }
    // Getter to get the current value of myProp
    get myProp(){return this._myProp;}

    // Inject the WebSQLService into your component to use
    constructor(private webSqlService: WebSQLService){}

    onInit(){
        // Load the initial state for the component
        this.webSqlService.read().then(x => this.myProp = x);
    }

    updateSql(value){
        // Save the value to storage
        this.webSqlService.update(value);
    }
}
```

This will essentially keep your storage and view in sync. You will need one piece I could not provide here which would be some way to listen if the value in the storage changed. This you could find in the WebSQL docs and then simply create a listener that would then call `this.webSqlService.read()` again which would then complete the "binding" and your view will change if your storage changes.

The second way to accomplish the above is to trigger the "Event" from the `update` `create` or `delete` methods of the WebSQLService class. Then your component could listen to it and then fetch the changes anew. Or more efficiently, the event could pass the change to the listener which would update `myProp` directly without another database read.

As you can see this is the basic pattern, but you will have to choose your implementation.